# How to make a git sparse checkout without having the whole repository in git/objects/pack?

Tags: git

Our .git/objects/pack directory is quite big and I would like to have a sparse checkout with the least possible disk space consumed.

Is it possible to make a sparse checkout and avoid having this directory and all its contents?

Comment: Check this article: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Packfiles . I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesn't make a lot of sense as written.  You are talking about the size of the objects pack file being large (which is a case of the repository history being big), but then you are talking about sparse checkout - which has to do with working directory space, and not repository space. You can have massive repository objects but a tiny working directory.

The `git clone --depth` answer already provided covers repository.

If you really want to do something goofy with your checkout operation I would try the following three commands

```
git read-tree --reset
git read-tree HEAD:<path to folder you are interested in>
git checkout-index
```

This should get you just a single directory in your working directory.  You wouldn't be able to make a (useful) commit though, you'd have to manually create tree objects and manually create commits.

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone --depth
```

Note: Shallow clones can't be used for Pushing anything as you will get Fast-Forward error

Comment: I don't think this fixes my problem, because I want to be able to access a specific file deep in the folder tree, but just its folder